# How to automatically create comparison pictures for a transcoded video file?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, comparison

How do one automatically/easily create a "before-after" comparison of two video file, where one file is the transcoded version of the other, in terms of several still images? Each pair would be created from the frame(s) at the same time code (not necessarily the same frame no.)

Comment: Have you come up with something already? What does "several" mean? Should that depend on the length of the video?

Comment: For practical reasons, "several" would be better as a fix number. However, the best would be an option for either use a fix number or use a trigger (like "take picture in every 5 minutes", or sg. more sophisticated).

Comment: @slhck I have no solution yet, I've included the ffmpeg tag only in hoping that the great video swiss knife could solve it.

Comment: Do you have a specific operating system in mind?

Comment: @slhck I currently use windows XPprosp3x32 and 7prox64, but any debian-based distro is also OK.

Comment: Comparing the two videos by watching them is usually considered a better method of comparison. The stills will not properly convey overall quality or allow you to easily recognize temporal artifacts while possibly making you overemphasize spatial artifacts. Also, you're introducing yet another format (source vs encoded vs image) into the factor for comparison.